# Console outputs Uncaught TypeError for .add in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, phaser-framework, tiled

I am making a 2D platformer game in which I am using the Phaser-framework (version 3.15.1) to make life easier, and a Tiled map for the first level of the game. I have exported the map from Tiled as a `.json` file, and read into the main JS file. However, in my index HTML file, where all fo teh JS files are ran from it comes up with the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read 
property 'add' of index.html:17 undefined 
at index.html:17
at index.html:20
```

Here is the relevant code:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Nightly Neighbours Using Phaser</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src = "js/phaser.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src = "js/phaser-arcade-physics.js"> 
    </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src = "js/Boot.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src = "js/Preload.js"></script>
        <script 
type="text/javascript"src="js/NightlyNeighbours1WithPhaser.js"> 
   </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            (function() {
                game = new Phaser.Game(window.innerWidth * 
                window.devicePixelRatio, 
                window.innerHeight * window.devicePixelRatio, Phaser.AUTO);
                game.state.add("Boot", Boot);
                game.state.add("Preload", Preload);
                game.state.add("NightlyNeighbours1WithPhaser", Main);
                game.state.start("Boot");
            })();
        </script>
</head>
```

The error refers to `lines 17 - 20`

Thanks a lot!

Comment: The error means that `game.state` is `undefined`. That is, there is either no property on the `game` object called "state", or there is but it has no value.

Comment: what is in `game.state`?

Comment: I didn't think, that it was necessary to define `game.state` so it has nothing it at the moment @DanielA.White @Pointy

Comment: How would I define `game.state` ? @Pointy

Comment: I have no idea; I don't know how that library works. If you're expecting it to have that particular API (the `.add()` method, and probably other things) then I don't think it's something you can do in your own code; it seems like it'd be something that the Phaser code would initialize.

Comment: Right, so, there could be an issue with either the phaser.js JavaScript file not initiating at all or being buggy?

Answer (score 0):

In Phaser 3 there was a change from using `state`s to instead using `scene`s. Based upon your code it looks like you're using Phaser 2 code with the Phaser 3 library.

There's a great official tutorial (with [Part 5](https://phaser.io/tutorials/getting-started-phaser3/part5) starting with the code aspect, since it appears you might have your environment setup already) that covers Phaser 3.

From that tutorial, the defining of the `Phaser.Game` looks something like the following:

```
var config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    physics: {
        default: 'arcade',
        arcade: {
            gravity: { y: 200 }
        }
    },
    scene: {
        preload: preload,
        create: create
    }
};

var game = new Phaser.Game(config);
```

You can also add new scenes to the game, by calling `game.scene.add(...)`.